# Como fazer UPDATE do valor de uma coluna usando a soma de outra tabela?

Tags: sql, servidor, sql-update, sum

Preciso fazer um UPDATE no valor de uma coluna, usando a soma de uma coluna de outra tabela. Tentei fazer assim mas não deu certo.

```
UPDATE  VENDAS 
   SET VALOR_TOTAL = (SELECT
      SUM (VI.QTDE) 
     FROM VENDA_ITENS VI    
     JOIN VENDAS V   
       ON VI.NUM_VENDA = V.NUM_VENDA   
    GROUP BY VI.NUM_VENDA)
WHERE NUM_VENDA = NUM_VENDA
```

Aparece o erro

> 'A subconsulta retornou mais de 1 valor. Isso não é permitido quando a
> subconsulta segue um =, !=, <, <= , >, >= ou quando ela é usada como
> uma expressão.'

Comment: `WHERE NUM_VENDA = NUM_VENDA` esse where não faz muito sentido, coloque a estrutura das tabelas pra ilustrar melhor.  "NUM_VENDA" não seria uma variável?

Answer (score 0):

Quanto ao erro que está pegando, ele diz que a *"subconsulta retornou mais de 1 valor"*; o `group by` agrupa os itens da tua tabela, então se existe mais de um `NUM_VENDA`, todos serão retornados. Nesse caso você precisa restringir a quantidade de itens retornados na sua consulta pra trazer apenas o *id* que precisa, por exemplo:

```
UPDATE VENDAS
SET VALOR_TOTAL = (SELECT SUM (VI.QTDE) 
                   FROM VENDA_ITENS VI    
                   JOIN VENDAS V ON VI.NUM_VENDA = V.NUM_VENDA   
                   WHERE WHERE NUM_VENDA = numero_venda --aqui é a restrição
                   GROUP BY VI.NUM_VENDA)
WHERE NUM_VENDA = numero_venda
```

Repare que passei a usar `numero_venda`; como [Ricardo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/57220/ricardo-pontual) comentou, esse cara provavelmente é uma variável que tem o número da venda específica.

Comment: Sim, entendi e dá certo quando eu coloco a restrição. Ex:  UPDATE VENDAS
SET VALOR_TOTAL = (SELECT SUM (VI.QTDE) 
                   FROM VENDA_ITENS VI    
                   JOIN VENDAS V ON VI.NUM_VENDA = V.NUM_VENDA   
                   WHERE V.NUM_VENDA = 3
                   GROUP BY VI.NUM_VENDA)
WHERE NUM_VENDA = 3                                            -- Mas eu preciso alterar todos os valores, ai não dá certo. Senão tenho que alterar um por um.

Answer (score -1):

Vê se assim pode te ajudar, como não tenho as estrutura da tabela não tenho como testar.

```
UPDATE VENDAS VE SET VALOR_TOTAL = (
    SELECT SUM (VI.QTDE) FROM VENDA_ITENS VI 
    WHERE VI.NUM_VENDA = VE.NUM_VENDA
) 
WHERE NUM_VENDA = NUM_VENDA
```